# How can I list all available printer drivers like the Add Printer Wizard in C#?

Tags: c#, printing

It may well be that I have to write something overly complex for this and that there is no regular way to do it, but:

How can I get myself a list of all available printer drivers much like the add printer wizard does when it displays them by manufacturer then by printer? I basically need a custom add printer dialog and without this, I'm a bit stuffed ;)

Like this: (ignore the arrow, borrowed image)

[image]

I would also need the path to the .inf file denoted by the drivers in the list

EDIT: A little background:

I am attempting to add a printer by invoking the add printer wizard (with elevated privs) in a TS session, adding the printer to the correct TS Port and then attempting to save the information for that printer so as upon login the users printer is added automatically based on values I've saved.

So far, I've not been able to find a way to get the driver information (preferably the actual path to the .inf file for that printer driver as then I can use PrintUI to install the printer) after adding the printer.

As such, I am resorting to a custom dialog to match the printer driver. As the tool is only used upon initial printer install and only by administrators I don't mind having a secondary dialog where you choose the driver a second time just so I can save the information.

EDIT: Targeting Windows Server 2008 R2 (Win32_PrinterDriver doesnt appear to work)

Comment: Try to parse all inf files in `%windir%\inf`. Good luck :-)

Comment: @rekire I was under the impression the drivers were located in %windir%\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository? Is that incorrect?

Comment: @DanielA.White well I wouldnt need it if I could get the information elsewhere, basically I'm adding a printer via printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /il which displays the wizard and I need to then replicate that on login - so I'm attempting to record what driver a printer is using in order to re-add it again upon login.

Comment: @DanielFrear Maybe also there. I just know that in the first path are always inf files.

Comment: @rekire just had a gander, I really hope theres a way to parse those without writing my own parser!

Comment: TS == _Terminal Services_? If so, the remote desktop client [already has the ability to do this](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/sushilasb/RemoteDesktopError/Remote%20Desktop%20connection%20solution.jpg). Or are you trying to add printers that are not mapped locally?

Comment: @DanielFrear - Possibly more directly related, all of the information you're looking for should be available through WMI. A combination of [Win32_Printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Win32_PrinterDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394366(v=vs.85).aspx) should get you on your way.

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes Terminal services, and yea - it *should* have the ability to do it but its not very good. From a PC client there's no problems, but from Thin Clients (especially older models) there's very little support

Comment: @DanielFrear did you ever produce a method for this? I am also looking to do the same thing. However, the accepted answer as you noted only gets you what is already installed.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I was able to produce what I needed from the accepted answer so I left it at that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query WMI for information on the printer drivers that are currently in use. The [Win32_PrinterDriver class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) details the available properties. You can use classes in the [System.Management Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwd0y33x.aspx) to perform the queries.

```
SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_PrinterDriver");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery);

foreach (ManagementObject printerDriver in searcher.Get()) 
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

You can access the properties by indexing to them, i.e. `printerDriver["DriverPath"]`.

Also see [WMI Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186146%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) topic on MSDN.

On an interesting side note, Microsoft has since added a [`Get-PrinterDriver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printerdriver?view=win10-ps) commandlet to some versions of PowerShell (on Windows 10, etc.) that does something pretty similar to the above code.

UPDATE: I was looking through old questions and discovered the [DriverStoreExplorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer) project on GitHub. There's a lot to the code that enumerates all printer drivers, so it does not make sense to reproduce it here.

Comment: This seems to give me a very small amount of printers, however - it may well be enough to achieve what I want as it's probably the list of drivers which are in use by installed printers, and at the time I'm going to use it, that would work.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. *All available* drivers is has been asked for.