# How can I get the list for all available printer drivers as in Printer Wizard?

Tags: c#, list, printing, driver

I would like to get a list for all printer drivers available in Windows, like that one in add printer wizard.

[image]

A quistion like this, has been asked here in the form 4 years ago. There was an answer refering to using the WMI for this purpose. But some how it is not working. Using that solution, I am getting only a list of installed printers.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: For reference, I'm guessing this is the question referred to in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791970/how-can-i-list-all-available-printer-drivers-like-the-add-printer-wizard-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but the solution there retrive only a list of installed printers and not a list for all available printer drivers!

Answer (score 0):

The printers you see in the printer wizard gets the available drivers from the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\DRIVERS\DriverDatabase\DeviceIds
```

This is a collection of drivers that includes printer drivers. I'm not exactly sure how the printer drivers are filtered, but you can access these values in C# using [`Registry.GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still need a list of all printers, and which printer is supported by which driver from the list in the registry?